# WSO2 APIM 4.2 http gateaway mixed content error

Tags: wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2 apim 4.2 with keycloak key manager to invoke an api through http. I published the api to get published through http and https, for the domain I already inject the ssl on wso2 apim.
I don't have any issue when invoke the api through https, but when I invoke it from http endpoint it returns failed to fetch with error

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://onyourdomain.com/test' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://onyourdomain.com/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

anyone have any insight what happened with it? Is there any settings missed for me to can access everything?

Comment: Can you see any errors in the server logs ?

Comment: no, there are no errors on the log